# Json object passing to a function fails in golang

Tags: json, go

In this program, I try pass a JSON object to a function and then to a REST API with `POST`. To do that I have following.

```
type resposeObj struct{
    uid     string `json :"uid"`
    service string `json : "service"`
}

response := resposeObj{uid:validatemailID.String(),service:"API Gateway"}

validateResponse,err := json.Marshal(response)

        if err != nil{
            log.Println("Error in marshaling data",err)
        }

        log.Println("Validate response byte slice: ",validateResponse)

err = sendResponse(validatemailResponse)
```

```
func sendResponse(req []byte)error{
    log.Println("Received response : ",string(req))
    return nil
}
```

And I get `Validate response byte slice:  [123 125]` as output. Which should be the byte array of Json object.

What am I missing here? Why its not converting to byte slice?

Comment: Unexported fields. The 100000 duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

you need to export the fields in your struct.
To achieve this in golang, you must capitalize the first letter of your fields.

```
type resposeObj struct{
    Uid     string `json : "uid"`
    Service string `json : "service"`
}
```